# How to open web page upon pressing the button in cocoa using objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, button

I have created one button in cocoa(mac) ,When I press that  button i want to redirect that to some web page. Can any one help me out.

Comment: Do you want to display the page in your program or launch a browser to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open URL in browser you need to call `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url]`

For a WebView included in your nib, just call `loadRequest:URL` on webView's mainframe object.

For ex:

```
[[_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the button in application and open the specific url in browser then you can go with "OpenUrl" method:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
```

If you want to open the page in your application then go with web view.